# Asp.Net Core não suporta System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Segue a propriedade criado do projeto **Asp.Net**:

```
public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Geo { get; set; }
```

Como posso fazer isso em projeto **Asp.Net Core 2.2** ?

Comment: Posso quase te garantir que não, o Core ainda tem algumas limitações nas coisas mais avançadas e mais "mosca branca", mas o 3.0 vem aí e pode ser que tenha, muita coisa entra nele.

Comment: @Maniero Outra alternativa seria `double` ?

Comment: Não sei te dizer, não ´pe um assunto que eu domino, mas duvido que seja uma substituição direta, no máximo uma alternativa meia boca. Note que estou especulando um pouco.

Comment: Se está a falar de Entity Framework Core sim ele existe

Comment: A pergunta não seria Entity Framework Core? a versão é a 2.2 que já foi apontado em resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a partir da versão do Ef Core 2.2

Para isso você precisa instalar os seguintes pacotes Nuget se usar Sql Server:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
```

Existem os pacotes para Postgres e SqlLite:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.NetTopologySuite
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite
```

Depois você precisa incluir no seu DbContext:

optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(

```
@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=WideWorldImporters",
x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
```

Para uma explicação completa aqui tem aqui na documentação oficial: [Spatial Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/spatial)